# How to get the count of all columns in all tables/views in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, counting

How do I get the count of all the columns in all views/tables in a given mysql database?

For example given a schema similar to:

| TABLE_1 | TABLE_2 | VIEW_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TABLE_1_COL_1 | TABLE_2_COL_1 | VIEW_1_COL_1 |
| TABLE_1_COL_2 |  |  |

I'd get:

| table_name | column_count |
| --- | --- |
| TABLE_1 | 2 |
| TABLE_2 | 1 |
| VIEW_1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in **information_schema** table to retrieve this:

```
SELECT information_schema.columns.table_name, count(*) as column_count
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE information_schema.columns.TABLE_SCHEMA = "YOUR_DB_NAME"
GROUP BY information_schema.columns.TABLE_NAME;
```

Furthermore you can filter by adding to the where clause; for example you can filter only the tables/views that have the prefix **v_** by adding to the where clause as follows:

```
SELECT information_schema.columns.table_name, count(*) as column_count
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE information_schema.columns.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'v\_%' AND
information_schema.columns.TABLE_SCHEMA = "YOUR_DB_NAME"
GROUP BY information_schema.columns.TABLE_NAME ;
```